# Media Converter - FX Link LIght Off

Tags: ethernet

At one end I have AF100-2 media convert 10/100Base and at the other end I have TP-Link MC200CM 10/1000Base media converter.

Originally there were AF100-2 at both ends, but one of device is not working, so bought a replacement.

On TP Link media converter there is no LED light for FX Link.

Do I need same kind of media converters at both end? Anything else I need to change?

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need media converters that "talk the same language" at both ends.

The AF100-2 appears to be 100Base-FX.

The MC200CM is 1000Base-SX.

I would also note that 1000Base-SX has a significantly lower maximum distance (220 or 500 meters depending on type of multimode fiber).  100Base-FX can go up to 2km, so if your fiber run is longer than 1000Base-SX can support, you will need to get a 100Base-FX media converter.